# Upload Images To Sitecore Using WebClient Method

Tags: sitecore, webclient, sitecore6

I have downloaded images from Sitecore to local folder using WebClient method and the path is as
~/media/BA6E6EA60496485489ABA4D5669D8949.ashx.
How to Upload Images To Sitecore

Answer (score 0):

You should use Sitecore Media Library or Content Editor to do the same. But as it is not clarified in question that are you asking to upload in Sitecore via usual shell interfaces or using some sort of services.

If you want to use webservice way than you can use number of ways which are as follows:
a) Sitecore Rocks WebService (If you are allowed to install that or it is already available).
b) Sitecore Razl Service(It is third party which need license).
c) [Sitecore Powershell Remoting](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/10/10/sitecore-powershell-extensions-remoting/) (This needs Sitecore PowerShell extensions to be installed on Sitecore Server).
d) You can also use Sitecore Service which you can find under sitecore\shell\WebService\Service.asmx (But this is legacy of new SitecoreItemWebAPI)
e) [Last is my enhanced SitecoreItemWebAPI](https://github.com/vishalniit/SitecoreItemWebAPI-CoreSync1.0) (This also need SitecoreItemWebApi 1.2 as a pre-requisite).

But in end except option d you need to install some or other thing in order to upload the image using HTTP, you should also know the valid credentials to use any of above stated methods.